# Angular 6 BehaviourSubject.next asking for value for class method

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to set a BehaviourSubject, but it's asking for a value for my class method:

```
private currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<LoggedInUser>({} as LoggedInUser);

this.currentUserSubject.next(
    {
        name: decodedJwtData.name,
        id: decodedJwtData.id,
        isGlobalAdmin: decodedJwtData.isGlobalAdmin === "True",
        currentRole: decodedJwtData.currentRole
    }
);
```

This is giving me an error "Property 'isAdmin' is missing in type"

```
export class LoggedInUser {
    name: string;  
    id: string;  
    isGlobalAdmin: boolean;
    currentRole: string;

    isAdmin() {
        return this.isGlobalAdmin || this.currentRole == Roles.Owner  || this.currentRole == Roles.Administrator;
    }
}
```

The class method is calculated, what should I supply it with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid `LoggedInUser` object that includes the `isAdmin()` method can be obtained with `new LoggedInUser()`. In the present case, you must supply such an object as the initial value for the `BehaviorSubject` and also as an argument to the `next` method.

You can define a class constructor with optional parameters:

```
export class LoggedInUser {

  constructor( 
    public name?: string,
    public id?: string,
    public isGlobalAdmin?: boolean,
    public currentRole?: string) {}

    isAdmin() {
        return this.isGlobalAdmin || this.currentRole == Roles.Owner  || this.currentRole == Roles.Administrator;
    }
}
```

The `BehaviorSubject` can then be initialized with `null` or with a default `LoggedInUser` object:

```
new BehaviorSubject<LoggedInUser>(null);
new BehaviorSubject<LoggedInUser>(new LoggedInUser());
```

and the `Behavior.next` method can be called with:

```
this.currentUserSubject.next(
  new LoggedInUser(
    decodedJwtData.name, 
    decodedJwtData.id, 
    decodedJwtData.isGlobalAdmin === "True", 
    decodedJwtData.currentRole)
);
```